# Erlang ets:insert_new for bag

Tags: erlang, ets

In my code I want to take advantage of ETS's bag type that can store multiple values for single key. However, it would be very useful to know if insertion actually inserts a new value or not (i.e. if the inserted key with value was or was not present in the bag).

With type set of ETS I could use ets:insert_new, but semantics is different for bag (emphasis mine):

> This function works exactly like insert/2, with the exception that instead of overwriting objects with the same key (in the case of set or ordered_set) or *adding more objects with keys already existing in the table* (in the case of bag and duplicate_bag), it simply returns false.

Is there a way to achieve such functionality with one call? I understand it can be achieved by a lookup followed by an optional insert, but I am afraid it might hurt performance of concurrent access.

Comment: The fastest way to check if a key is present is to use `ets:member/2` which just returns `true` or `false`. There is no way with ETS to atomically make multiple accesses to an ETS table. It is a simple store no a db.

Comment: I cannot use `ets:member/2` as I need to check both key and value (ets has type bag).